# How do I show admin_notice after submitting a custom form which is rendered by function in WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a simple WordPress plugin where admin can create user roles using an admin form. I want to display an `admin_notice` if a role is already existing.

Problem I am having is even the role exists, the message is not appearing. If I understand properly, this is because the form is actually being redirected to `admin-post.php`. If so, how can I show the admin_notice after submission?

In short I have this:

- One function in my plugin to render the form.
- One function to save. Before saving, WP checks whether role exists. If yes, I want to display an admin_notice and "return". Otherwise, role gets saved.

The code snippet to check and show `admin_notice`:

```
<?php

function save_user_role()
{
    $role_name = $_POST['role_name'];
    $role_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($role_name);
    $role = get_role($role_slug);
    if (!empty($role))
    {
        $notice = 'Role exists';
        do_action('admin_notices', $this->display_notice($notice));

        // return; // If I use the return the correct message coming up in a blank page.

    }
    else
    {

        // Save the role

    }
}
```

Below is the full code that I have written

```
function save_user_role() {
   // Role already exists?
   $role_name = $_POST[ 'coolmedia_role_name' ];
   $role_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $role_name );
   $role = get_role( $role_slug );

   if( ! empty( $role ) ) {
      // Error. Role already exists
      $notice = 'Speficed role ' . $role_name . ' already exists';
      do_action( 'admin_notices', $this->display_notice( $notice ) );
   } else {
     // Safe to create the new role
     $role_caps = array(
       'read'  => true,
     );

     ...

     add_role( $role_slug, esc_html( $role_name ), $role_caps );

     // Redirect back to form page
     wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=user-roles' ) );
   }
}
```

Display notice function:

```
function add_user_role_markup() { ?>
     <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Add Role</h1>
        <form method="post" action="<?php esc_html(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>">
        <table class="form-table">
           <tr class="first">
              <th>Role name</th>
              <td><input required type="text" id="role_name" name="role_name" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th>
                   <?php
('coolmedia-role-save', 'coolmedia-role-nonce'); ?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_user_role">
               </th>
               <td><?php
('Save Role'); ?></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when `save_user_role` is being called and what else happens after that function. It's possible that the `admin_notices` hook is firing, but that (as you suggest) there's a redirect happening which would cause it *not* to fire after the redirect because (rightfully) `save_user_role` isn't being called again, or that `save_user_role` is firing *after* the `admin_notices` hook is called (in which case you're too late).

One solution might be to temporarily store an option in the database with your notice, and then check for it and display it as needed if it exists. This way, WordPress can do its redirect and then check for and display your notice when it returns.

Something like this. (Note: my `add_action` assumes this is happening in a class which I assume is how you've structured it based on your use of `$this->display_notice()`)

```
function save_user_role(){
  ...
  if( ! empty( $role ) ) {
    // Error. Role already exists
    $notice = 'Specified role ' . $role_name . ' already exists';
    update_option( 'coolmedia_role_exists_message', $notice, 'no' );
  }
  ...
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'maybe_display_notice' ) );
function maybe_display_notice(){
  $notice = get_option( 'coolmedia_role_exists_message', false );
  if( $notice ){
    delete_option( 'coolmedia_role_exists_message' );
    $this->display_notice( $notice );
  }
}

function display_notice( $notice ){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to change one thing in `maybe_display_option`. `$notice = update_option( 'coolmedia_role_exists_message', false );`  to `$notice = get_option( 'coolmedia_role_exists_message', false );`. Please update your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry about that! I updated the answer for future visitors. Good catch and glad it worked out!